# The phpMyAdmin repo on GitHub is a Dev (uninstalled) version. Thus many files are NOT even there. How do we commit fixes to THOSE missing files?

Tags: git, phpmyadmin, git-commit

I have a lot of experience with PHP/MySQL but not much with Git. I figure this question should be an easy one for you but I can't figure it out and would really appreciate you answer(s).

Here is my question: I've downloaded and installed phpMyAdmin from Git using the "composer update" and "yarn install --production" commands. Then I fixed a bug that happens to be in the \themes\pmahomme\css\theme.css file. So far so good but when I tried "commit"-ing the change it turns out the file theme.css in NOT EVEN THERE on the original GitHub repo, due to - it's a Dev repo (it's NOT installed) and the \themes\pmahomme\css\ folder is actually empty (no files at all there).

-- How do you go about this situation? How do you commit?
I would really appreciate you throw in there a couple of commands as well if that is of importance.

Thank you all!

Angelo

Comment: My guess is that your build process generated a file not tracked by the repo you checked out.  Do a `git ls-files` and `grep` for the file that you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you Andy. You were right and I eventually I found more specifics about it.